# Computing the relations in invariant algebra

Tags: classical-invariant-theory, ac.commutative-algebra

Suppose we have a ring $R$ and a finite group $G$ acting on it, Is there a way to compute the invariant ring $R^G$ explicitly? Infact I am more interested in the case of affine ring and the symmetric group acting on it and I want to have the relations in the invariant ring explicitly.

More presicely, I have an algebra having finitely many generators and finitely many relation and the symmetric group acts on it. I want to have the relations in the invariant ring explicitly. I could not find a way to do so in the books I have seen so far.

Comment: To second Liviu's comment, you should also be more specific about the action of the symmetric group you are interested in. The case of multi-symmetric polynomials where S_n rigidly permutes groups of variables is for instance much more complicated than the obvious action of S_n on C^n.

Comment: @ Abdelmalek and Liviu I mean the ring of functions on an arbitrary affine variety and the obvious action of the symmetric group. I am going to have a look on the article and book mentioned. Thank you for your responses.

Answer (score 2):

Can you be more specific  on the meaning of affine ring? More precisely do you mean the ring of function on an *arbitrary*  affine variety or just the ring of functions on $\mathbb{C}^n$? In any case,  this [nice  article of R. Stanley](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1979-01-03/S0273-0979-1979-14597-X/home.html) may be a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

See the book ["Invariant Theory of Finite Groups"](http://books.google.com/books?id=tLEyb4qhaRoC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false)
by Neusel and Smith, as well as [this other book](http://books.google.com/books?id=sHQ5E_t76S8C&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Derksen and Kemper.